# Why does my table look so weird when I import the csv file?

Tags: sql, csv

for school I have to import this csv file into my database but there is something I'm missing. I can't find anything in my books about it and I wouldn't know how to google for this stuff so I hope someone can point me in the right direction on what it is I'm doing wrong or what I am not getting.

this is how it looks when I try to add it

[image: 1]

Does anyone know why it looks all messed up like that?

I tried multiple videos on how to import csv to sql but no video covers this problem. I have no clue what this is.

Comment: It seems that your CSV file is malformed; open it with a basic text editor and check what's inside

Comment: Seems that row-1 (or maybe row-2) became your column header. Determine if your CSV has headers and properly import. If using an import wizard, it mostly likely has a check-box for "file has headers".

Comment: 2nd what @Fravadona said.  Open the source file in a text editor and you should see the issue.  I suggest Textpad.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (This is not a general SQL problem.)